# Kafka JDBC sink connector is not creating new postgreSQL tables in real-time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am writing a test to check if my JDBC Kafka connector creates a postgres new table properly, when I publish topics with new names. **Although the creation eventually works**, the postgres table is created with a delay (some minutes), and therefore my real-time test fails.

I wonder if there is a way to force the JDBC connector to create postgres tables in real-time.

**test_connector.py**

```
from mymodule.producer import produce
from mymodule.athlete import Athlete
import unittest
import psycopg2


class TestConnector(unittest.TestCase):
    ''' Test for JDBC Kafka Connector '''

    conn = psycopg2.connect("postgres://******")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    def test_table_auto_create(self, topic_name=sometopic_test'):
        ''' Tests whether a postgreSQL table is auto-created when the producer publishes a new topic.
            Topic name must match the regex: sometopic_(.*)

            Args:
                topic_name (str): The name of the topic (default: 'sometopic_test')
            '''
        produce(topic_name)
        self.cursor.execute(
            f"SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS result FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND tablename = '{topic_name}');")
        table_created = self.cursor.fetchone()[0]

        self.assertEqual(table_created, True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Connector config**

```
{
    "name": "jdbc_sink",
    "connector.class": "io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "****",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "***",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "***",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "***",
    "topics.regex": "sometopic_(.*)",
    "connection.url": "***",
    "connection.user": "****",
    "connection.password": "***",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "table.name.format": "${topic}",
    "auto.create": "true"
}
```

Comment: How are you defining "real time"? You should update your question with log/timing details show describe the behaviour you are observing, including the timestamp of the message as it arrives on Kafka, when it is read by Kafka Connect, and when the sink writes to the database (you might need `TRACE` logging on the Kafka Connect worker)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt To begin with, thanks for all the amazing videos and blog tutorials. Lots of respect for you. Your work has been really valuable to me. I will try to debug the way you proposed and I'll come back if I am not able to solve this.